# Move footer column after space is freed up (ipad viewport)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress (latest version) I have successfully hidden middle column in the footer (there are three in total) using the following CSS code:

```
@media (width: 768px) and (height: 1024px) { .footer-widget:nth-child(2) { display: none; } }
```

However, this doesnt move the third column up to where the second one was (which is what I want to achieve).

Please see the image below for reference:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I am using the Divi theme and latest version of Wordpress. I can save any code into the custom CSS or JS areas.

Comment: Are these widgets? Kindly share links

Comment: any live demo we can see?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Unfortunately the site is in a staging area, so nothing live right now. But appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it into tablet size screen.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .footer-widget:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-widget {
    float: left;
    width: 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-footer">
  <div class="footer-widget">
    <h3>
    GET IN TOUCH
    </h3>
    <button>
      Live Chat
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget">
    <h3>
    yoour display none content
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget">
    <h3>
    USEFUL RESOURCES
    </h3>
    <button>
      About Us
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified it slightly (below) but you got me onto the correct path.

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footer-widget:nth-child(2) { display: none; }
  .footer-widget:nth-child(3) { float:right; }
  .footer-widget:nth-child(n) { margin: 0px !important; }
}

Comment: Never forget to clear float after it. if divi builder not clear it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Most welcome. If any query have in mind regarding wordpress, php, css, js please share with me i highly appreciate it